# How to validate object used as foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

**Django==2.2.5**

Could you help me validate if object used as foreign key is not archived?

The problem: parent_is_archived(obj) receives int as its argument. For example, 1. It is not an object where I can check its fields. And there is no sign of the model whose pk this int represents.

Maybe I should redefine some method like clean_fields?

```
class Level_1(models.Model):
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                   verbose_name="Archived")

def parent_is_archived(obj):
    if ...:
        message = 'Parent object is archived'
        raise ValidationError(message)

class Level_2(models.Model):
    parent_level = models.ForeignKey(Level_1,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     validators=[parent_is_archived])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the save method instead:

```
class Level_2(models.Model):
    parent_level = models.ForeignKey(Level_1,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     validators=[parent_is_archived])

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if self.parent_level.archived:
          raise Exception('....')
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

*Alternatively,* you can use [**`Model.clean()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method as well, where you can put the restrictions:

```
class Level_2(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
      if self.parent_level.archived:
           raise ValidationError('...')
```

And use `instance.full_clean()` to invoke the clean method. For example:

```
def some_view(request):
     form = LevelTwoForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
         instance = form.save(commit=False)
         instance.full_clean()
         instance.save()
     # rest of the code
```

Comment: Why not redefining clean_fields?

Comment: do you mean overriding clean_fields() method?

Comment: Yes, that method.

Comment: you don't need to. As per [implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L1217), it returns id of the FK. Also, I think I misunderstood your question, and the int you are getting its the PK of `Level_1`. Hence you can get the object by `instance=Level_1.objects.get(pk=obj)`

Comment: In my case validator is made to be reusable. I have several levels. For example your comment abowe will not help in case of Level_5.

Comment: in that case you can create a base abstract model with clean method, and subclass all your Level models from that; it will make the code more reusable